# How to get the network user who is executing the transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got a task from my customer on his existing SQL Server database.

They have a database with 1 user with all admin rights. They manage the accessibility rights on the application level.

The task is to create an audit table, to audit who INSERT, UPDATE, & DELETE from database tables.

The structure of this table is simple:
   TableName
   Operation {INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE}
   TimeStamp,
   UserName

The audit log is requested to be on server side through triggers.

So it is an EASY Task: Add Trigger to each table & each Event. Inside the trigger, insert a new row to Audit Table with Values of (TableName, Operation, TimeStamp, & UserName).

The problem is the username (SQL: SYSTEM_USER) is always the same for all users as they all connect with the same admin account.

Is there anyway, in SQL server, to get the network user name who is making the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I should have made some researches before asking. Anyway, it could be useful to others.

I found this function [Host_Name()], which returns the name of the computer that makes the transaction.